# WinScp SFTP -no supported authentication methods available google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sftp, winscp

While connecting google cloud with WinScp SFTP Connwction gives the no supported authentication methods available google cloud error (Server Sent:public key) Any Solution ?

[image]

Comment: I got this error. For me it was fixed it by setting enable-oslogin:FALSE in google cloud settings instead of TRUE and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you could make a clearer question, it would help you to obtain a good response. Nonetheless, let me provide mine.

Google Cloud Platform documentation has a section to connect to your VM instances through the WinScp client. The most probable cause of your issue is the absence or a wrong configuration of your public or private key.

If you already have a pair of keys try to look for them, [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#locatesshkeys) can help you. But if not, your should create a pair of private-public keys, for example to create such keys in Linux this command is normally used:

```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

be aware of leaving blank the passphrase to ensure a straightforward connection and no other password will be required during the connection from WinScp. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#createsshkeys) you can find the complete steps to do that.

Afterwards, you have to be able to configure your private key in you WinScp client in the Authentication section, just like it is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#winscp).

Hope it helps you!